# iOS Bluetooth Discovery and Pairing

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I want my app to take care of the bluetooth discovery, pairing and connection process but my current understanding is that in order for my app to see what devices are available to connect to it must have been manually paired through ios Settings first. Is there any way I can achieve my goal without relying on the user to pair first through settings?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Articles/Connecting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009499-SW1

Comment: Is your peripheral an MFi device using legacy Bluetooth or is it a BLE peripheral?

Comment: There are 2 devices, both have Mfi mode, both are classic. One is bluetooth 2.1 and the other is 3.0

Comment: You should be able to use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/eaaccessorymanager/1613913-showbluetoothaccessorypicker)

Comment: @Paulw11 You should add your comment as an answer.